# Delete liste with Mailchimp API V3 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mailchimp

I want to delete a list with the Mailchimp API V3 Gem. With this code, no errors returned, but the list is not deleted:

```
mailchimp = Mailchimp.connect(Rails.application.config.mailchimp_api_key)
    payload = {
                id: 'ac45e6f2f'
            }
mailchimp.lists.delete payload
```

Thanks

**Fixed :**

Working with `mailchimp.lists(list_id).delete`

Comment: What gem are you using?

Comment: I use this gem : http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailchimp_api_v3/0.0.6

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the documentation the `delete` method. It seems you are hitting `Enumerable#delete` instead.

Comment: Is now fixed. Working with mailchimp.lists(list_id).delete